# Mozilla Firefox parseFloat slow performance

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have following code, used in my custom table sort preprocessing

```
var tstart = performance.now();
var sortablearr = new Array(Math.floor((activeTRTable.rows.length / 2)));
var arr_i = 0;

console.log("Starting preprocessing...")
//0 index is table head
var t1buff = 0
var t2buff = 0
var t3buff = 0
for (i = 1; i < activeTRTable.rows.length; i += 2) {
    var t0 = performance.now();

    var x = parseFloat(activeTRTable.rows[i].cells[DURATIONTYPE].innerText);
    var y = parseFloat(activeTRTable.rows[i].cells[DURATIONTYPE].innerText);

    var t1 = performance.now();
    t1buff += (t1 - t0)

    var content = new Array(4)

    var t2 = performance.now();
    t2buff += (t2 - t1)

    content[TABLEITEM] = activeTRTable.rows[i]
    content[HIDDENDETAILITEM] = activeTRTable.rows[i + 1]
    content[HIDDENDETAILITEM + 1] = x
    content[HIDDENDETAILITEM + 2] = y
    sortablearr[arr_i] = content
    arr_i += 1

    var t3 = performance.now();
    t3buff += (t3 - t2)
}
var tpreprocessed = performance.now();
console.log("Preprocessing ended in " + (tpreprocessed - tstart) + " milliseconds.")
console.log("T1B: " + t1buff)
console.log("T2B: " + t2buff)
console.log("T3B: " + t3buff)
```

This code seems to result into very insufficient behavior in Mozilla browser, especially the parseFloat part.
There are results from various browsers:

**Opera**

```
Preprocessing ended in 56.89500000000044 milliseconds.
T1B: 35.88000000001557
T2B: 4.690000000055079
T3B: 8.65999999995438
```

**Internet Explorer**

```
Preprocessing ended in 372.7204875779862 milliseconds.
T1B: 248.5273986186603
T2B: 17.503554555074515
T3B: 66.14627339602884
```

**Edge**

```
Preprocessing ended in 457.5451515628629 milliseconds.
T1B: 320.98263165675325
T2B: 9.163721063269804
T3B: 91.9268633019874
```

**Google Chrome**

```
Preprocessing ended in 51.73499999999876 milliseconds.
T1B: 33.16500000007545
T2B: 4.495000000026266
T3B: 7.229999999955908
```

**Mozilla Firefox (55.0.3 (32-bit))**

```
Preprocessing ended in 31678.250000000004 milliseconds.
T1B: 31622.514999999778
T2B: 17.620000000077198
T3B: 21.96500000006563
```

What is going on!? How to fix this code for mozilla?

`cells[DURATIONTYPE].innerText` contains just simple floating point number XX.XX, rounded on 2 decimals (i.e. 43.21).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure the slow thing is accessing the DOM (`activeTRTable.rows[i].cells[DURATIONTYPE].innerText`) and **not** parseFloat.

Quoting MDN (emphasis mine) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows

> The HTMLTableElement.rows read-only property **returns a live HTMLCollection** of all the rows in the table.

I assume it is generated *as you access* the property and not kept ready for you at all times. You should not work on the DOM directly but cache everything in your own data structures and treat the DOM as write only.

Edit: as a quick fix try caching the `rows` property before the loop. However, the `cells` property behaves similar.

Comment: Yes, you are partially right. It was caused by that part. But caching rows did not really seem to help. Instead, changing .innerText to .innerHTML did the magic. Wohoo, Preprocessing ended in 37.97 milliseconds.